# localization in swift 5 (change language button doesn't work)

Tags: ios, swift5

first of all I added my arabic language and all set and I tested it with example but my problem when I tap change language button it should change the language from arabic to English and the reverse of it successfully bit it seems it doesn't work and I saw videos this example worked with swift2 is there is a problem here if I did something wrong because I added a code in AppDelegate not SceneDelegate..that's all I know: now here is my code

//change language button in my viewController, and the rootVC is my storyboard id:

```
@IBAction func changelanguage(sender:UIButton) {
        if Language.currentLanguage() == "ar" {
            Language.setAppLanguage(lang: "en-US")
        }else{
            Language.setAppLanguage(lang: "ar")

        }
        let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window

        let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        window?.rootViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootVC")
    }

//and here is my Language swift file :

import Foundation

class Language {

   class func currentLanguage() -> String {
    let def = UserDefaults.standard

             let langs = def.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! NSArray
        let firstLang = langs.firstObject as! String

         return firstLang
        }

    class func  setAppLanguage(lang: String) {
        let def = UserDefaults.standard

        def.set([lang, currentLanguage()],forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        def.synchronize()
    }
}

//and the swift file called Localizer:

import Foundation

class Localizer {
    class func doTheExchange(){
        exchangeMethodsForClass(className: Bundle.self, originalSelector: #selector(Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)), overrideSelector: #selector(Bundle.customLocalizedStringForKey(key:value:table:)))
    }

}

    extension Bundle {
        @objc func customLocalizedStringForKey(key:String, value: String?,table tableName: String) -> String {


        let currentLanguage = Language.currentLanguage()

        var bundle = Bundle()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType:"lproj") {
            bundle = Bundle(path: path)!
        }else{
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")
            bundle = Bundle(path: path!)!
        }
        return bundle.customLocalizedStringForKey(key: key, value: value, table: tableName)

    }

}

func exchangeMethodsForClass(className:AnyClass, originalSelector:Selector,overrideSelector:Selector){

    let originalMethod:Method = class_getInstanceMethod(className, overrideSelector)!
    let overrideMethod:Method = class_getInstanceMethod(className, overrideSelector)!

    if class_addMethod(className, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod)){

    class_replaceMethod(className, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    }else{

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, overrideMethod)
    }
}

and finally my AppDelegate file:
and here is my question is the problem from here !!
//should I do this in sceneDelegate not AppDelegate !! , if yes how can I do this in SceneDelegate

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Localizer.doTheExchange()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a typo and are assigning the same selector to both methods.  Perhaps this would work:

```
func exchangeMethodsForClass(className:AnyClass, originalSelector:Selector,overrideSelector:Selector){

    let originalMethod:Method = class_getInstanceMethod(className, overrideSelector)!
    let overrideMethod:Method = class_getInstanceMethod(className, originalSelector)!
```

Comment: hi thanks @HalR I replaced both of them ,now it gave me window with nill is it from sceneDelegate because my reference here AppDelegate!!

Comment: You had one mis-copy.  I'd recommend that you very carefully go through the rest of the code and see if it matches up. I don't think it matters that its in the AppDelegate.  I've had swizzling in there before.